# 301 redirect in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to redirect a url from one domain to another domain in nginx.

`URL 1 - http://domain1/event/ert123`

`URL 2 - http://domain2/event/dfe456`

I have used the following code but doesn't work.

```
   #Test event
   location /event/ert123 {
        return 301 http://domain2.com/$request_uri
   }
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `$request_uri`? Maybe something like this?

```
  location /event/ert123 {
        return 301 http://domain2.com/event/dfe456
   }
```

Comment: Worked Thanks a lot.